# Pointers and input in user define functions

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

In this I called a `add()` function by reference my doubt is how does it send input in this case. I mean does it use &p = a and does `&(any variable)` represent address of variable?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void add(int &p)
{
    p++;
}
int main()
{
    int a=55;
    add(a);
    
    cout<<a;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `func(int &p)` means passing by reference, in this case a reference to the original variable that is passed is used and no copy is made. If you would `cout << &a` you'll get the memory address.

Comment: @interjay compiling just fine

Comment: `&` is used for several different purposes in C++. In a type `&` means reference, e.g. `int& p` means `p` is a reference to an integer. In an expression `&` means address of, e.g. `&a` would be the address of `a`.

Comment: @Waqar That's because the question was edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does &(any variable) represent address of variable?

Yes.

#### What are references?

Simply put, references are just aliases. That means `p` is just another way to *refer* to `a`. Any changes you make to `p` or `a` will be reflected in the other. However, you cannot reassign the reference variable to something else. References are just initialized once and reused afterwards.

Example:

```
int main()
{
    int a=55;
    int &p = a; //p is referring to a
    p++;        // a = 56, p = 56
    a = 100;    // a = 100, p = 100
    
     //address of both are same as well
    cout << &a << '\n';
    cout << &p << '\n';
    
    int x = 33;
    p = &x; // error
    &p = x; // error, can't change
    p = x; //ok, but now a = 33, p = 33, (p is not referring to x)
}
```